# Keep Hibernate Initializer from Crashing Program

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I have a Java program using a basic Hibernate session factory. I had an issue with a hibernate hbm.xml mapping file and it crashed my program even though I had the `getSessionFactory()` call in a try catch

```
                try
                {
                    session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession();    
                    session.beginTransaction();
                    rh = getRunHistoryEntry(session);
                    if(rh == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("No run history information found in the database for run id " + runId_ + "!");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.error("Error initializing hibernate");
                }
```

It still manages to break out of this try/catch and crash the main thread. How do I keep it from doing this? The main issue is I have a bunch of cleanup commands that NEED to be run before the main thread shuts down and need to be able to guarantee that even after a failure it still cleans up and goes down somewhat gracefully. The session factory looks like this:

```
public class SessionFactoryUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;  

    static {  
        try 
        {  
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml  
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } 
        catch (Throwable ex) 
        {  
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed  
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);  
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);  
        }  
    }  

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() 
    {   try
        {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }  
}
```

The error thrown is the following, and I have fixed it, but I would like to safeguard against any hibernate initializing error from stopping the main thread.

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource hibernate/TmdIndataLine.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.ryanco.db.SessionFactoryUtil.<clinit>(SessionFactoryUtil.java:19)
    at com.ryanco.rta.RtaMain.main(RtaMain.java:148)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource hibernate/TmdIndataLine.hbm.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1635)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1603)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1582)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1556)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1476)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1462)
    at com.ryanco.db.SessionFactoryUtil.<clinit>(SessionFactoryUtil.java:13)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:555)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:613)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 114 of document  : The element type "class" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</class>". Nested exception: The element type "class" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</class>".
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:546)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: What information does the crash give?

Comment: @Mark: I added it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static initializer in SessionFactoryUtil has a try/catch for all instances of Throwable but your main try/catch block only catches Exceptions. I'd change it to catch Throwables as well and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately it had the same effect.

Comment: I read your solution incorrectly. I implemented catching throwable in my main try/catch (like you said) and that solved it. It was a long day.

Comment: @manyxcxi I'm glad that helped. Good luck with your project and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on what type of application you write, static initializers doing anything that reaches outside of the JVM are usually a bad idea.

To the problem: if I read you code correctly, you first catch all `Throwable`s in the static initalizer of `SessionFactoryUtil`, write an error message to standard error **an then throw a new `ExceptionInInitializerError` yourself**, wrapping the catched `Throwable` in it.

IIRC static initializers are invoked first thing after the class was loaded. The stack trace tells us this happens probably from the main method in class `RtaMain`, as `SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory()` seems to be invoked from there, which triggers the class load.

To catch this error you need a try/catch surrounding the call to `getSessionFactory()` in the main method of your class `RtaUtil`, catching Throwable, or at least the specific throwable you throw in your static initializer yourself, which is `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

> It still manages to break out of this try/catch and crash the main thread.

As mentioned, this bloc in your main method won't catch the `ExceptionInInitializerError` thrown in your static initializer:

```
catch(Exception ex) {
    logger.error("Error initializing hibernate")
}
```

If you want to catch both `Exception` and `Error`, you should `catch (Throwable t)` (by the way, I noticed you said you changed that but I'd like to see what you changed exactly and the error you get.

But to be honest, if the `SessionFactory` fails at being initialized, I wonder what you're going to do in your `main` method and it's actually a common practice to let the program fail in that case.

Last thing, the `try/catch` in this part seems totally useless:

```
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    try {
        return sessionFactory;
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can remove it safely.

Comment: Steven was correct, I implemented his solution in the wrong spot in my code initially. The main issue I have with needing to catch everything and close gracefully is that the program updates a status xml file that keeps a number of web apps updated as to what is happening. When I catch a fatal exception the program stops its normal execution path, updates the status file that it is finished but had errors and shuts down. I don't expect to have hibernate issues as it was a typo in an hbm.xml file but I didn't want to leave loose ends.